# XSD element with undefined contents

Tags: xsd

I need to rig up an XSD schema that will validate files partially. The file structure is:

```
<Root>
    <Node name="core">
        <ElementA>String</ElementA>
        <ElementB>String</ElementB>
    </Node>
    <Node name="something unique">
        (any number of elements, with unknown names and types)
    </Node>
</Root>
```

My XSD is something like:

```
<xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Node">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>                        
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Which is incomplete and not entirely correct, the un-named `<xs:element>` is invalid.

There are a few nodes that are required, as well as each node having a unique name attribute; this is what I want to validate. The list of names, and the contents of those nodes, is predefined.

The contents of nodes with unknown names is also unknown, and may contain any number of elements with any name and type, but must not have attributes or values themselves.

The part I'm having trouble with is allowing child elements without knowing their names.

Is it at all possible to do something like this with XSD? Is there a way to have a complex type of elements, or anyType, and an attribute?

**Edit:** It would be just as acceptable to use the `<Node>` `name`s as the element type, and then simply allow additional elements with unknown names. Either way, I need to allow nodes with unknown name and type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow "child elements without knowing their names" you could use xsd:any; add it as a repeating particle after your specific (known at "design time") content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Node">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ElementA" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="ElementB" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Extensions" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded"     processContents="lax"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: So you suggest differentiating between the required and optional elements? In this case, having two (or more) names?

Comment: Yes. However, you don't have to put the xsd:any under a wrapper element if that is what you mean; yet, it is a rather common pattern. One thing I would do different though would be to define a global complex type for the Extensions element to allow for someone that uses your schema to do their own redefines in case they want to "strong type" it. I was just trying to quickly show you how xsd:any could satisfy your requirements the way I understood them.